# Show that if Frechet (d) derivative is exist this implies that Gateaux derivative is exist.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimal-control

Show that if Frechet (d) derivative is exist this implies that Gateaux (D) derivative is exist , and D f(x)= d f(x), and show that the opposite is not true always and why?

my solution

suppose that the f-derivative exist

$\lim_{\| k \| \to 0} 
\frac{\| T(x+k)-T(x)-dT(x)k)\| }{\| k\|}=0 \quad Put \quad k=\alpha h \rightarrow $
$\lim_{\| \alpha \| \to 0} \frac{ \| T(x+\alpha h-T(x)-dT(x)\alpha h\|}{\|\alpha h \|}=0 $

By tailor series:

$ T(x+\alpha h)=T(x)+\alpha dT(x)h+h O(\alpha) \leftrightarrow T(x+\alpha h)-T(x)=\alpha dT(x)h+h O(\alpha)$

$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{T(x+\alpha h)-T(x)-dT(x)\alpha h}{\alpha} = 0$

$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{T(x+\alpha h)-T(x)}{\alpha} -dT(x)h = 0$

$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{T(x+\alpha h)-T(x)}{\alpha} =dT(x)h$

and i can't do second term of question "and show that the opposite is not true always and why?" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f\colon \mathbf R^2 \rightarrow \mathbf R$ defined by $f(0,0)=0,\enspace f(x,y) = \dfrac{xy^3}{x^2+y^6}$. It is Gâteaux-derivable at $(0,0)$, but not Fréchet-derivable.
Indeed, if it were Fréchet-derivable, it should be continuous at $(0,0)$. *Hint:* let $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ along the curve $x=y^3$.

Comment: thank @Bernard but how can write " Why"

Comment: @mjd: see my updated answer.

Comment: I can't understand this relation between Frechet and Gateaux

Comment: @mjd Roughly, Fréchet derivable means differentiable (local continuous linear approximation – in finite dimension, continuous is redundant), while Gâteaux it has a directional derivative in all directions, and such derivative is a continuous function of the direction. It's well known that having directional derivatives in all directions is not enough to ensure differentiability in the case of more than one variable.

Comment: is it mean that Gâteaux in one dimension is Fréchet

Comment: @mjd: That's right.

Comment: I am very very thank you @Bernard